# Simple collision or pathing in 2d map

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm struggling to do my collision for the walls in a maze game i'm making for school.
I got an idea to actually just put the X and Y coordinates of the the "allowed path" as the map is drawn out to get the coordinates that the player can move within.
But i can't really get it to work properly, any pointers and help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm pasting below the code snippet for the movement of the player and the beginning of the pathing i'v come up with.

```
function gameLoop() {
                    ctxPc.clearRect(0, 0, pcCanvas.width, pcCanvas.height);
                    if (playerUp == true) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < allowedPathY.length; i++) {
                            if (positionY == allowedPathY[i]) {
                                positionY -= moveSpeed;
                            }

                        }
                        //positionY -= moveSpeed;
                    }
                    else if (playerDown == true) {
                        positionY += moveSpeed;
                    }
                    if (playerLeft == true) {
                        positionX -= moveSpeed;
                    }
                    else if (playerRight == true) {
                        positionX += moveSpeed;
                    }
                    drawPlayer(positionX, positionY);
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
                    console.log(positionX, positionY);
                }
                gameLoop();
```

The moving around is working fine, just really gotta get that pathing done!

Edit: yes i know the above if statement will not work, but I can't get my head around to how to move forward here for this idea to work. I strongly feel it's the best way (idea-wise) to go on this instead of making the walls collisiondetected.

Comment: If you really want to use allowedPathY, you should not do this loop thing you're doing. Instead make it a map of { Ycoord ( integer ) -> canMoveThere ( boolean ) } so you can write `if ( allowedPathY[ positionY ] )`. Also, probably check `positionY + 1` instead as this is the place you're trying to get to.

Comment: I see what you mean, very good idea. I was also thinking of actually making a multidimensional array for the allowedpath and store x,y for each "cell" in it to see exactly where the player are, might be better since the allowedPathY values are alot of the same in a row (lots of 32's followed by lots of 64's... etc)

Comment: what do you mean with loop thing? the function that calls itself at the end ? it's kinda needed though as its gonna be my main gameloop. all animations for both playerchar and monsterchars is updated through it. I have now tried even more different ways but nothing seems to work. at one point i am thinking of adding all walls along the x-axis and make them separate objects that i then can collide with. but i just wonder if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: The `for (let i = 0; i < allowedPathY.length; i++)` loop can be replaced with checking a single entry in an array given that its sorted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i solved it, finally!

I'm not gonna paste all code that went into it cause it would be a wall of code.

But what i finally did was that i always checked what "cell" the playerCharacter was in and checked all four directions for possible ways. Then if there was a path i made a new rectangle shape for Vertical movement and one for Horizontal movement and just made a rectangular collision check within that shape = movement true.
I can post code though if anyone is interested. But consider this question solved.